# MVC - overriding @Html.DropDownListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With MVC, I normally do a lot of custom display/editor templates which work perfectly fine for custom created model classes.

However, with the limitation of how to style drop downs (select elements), I created some styling which output a different set of elements to the standard.

Does anyone know of how to properly override the output from @Html.DropDownListFor() so that every drop down in my solution will change? Are there any resources on-line for this?

The method itself can be found in System.Web.Mvc.dll, but wanted some resources for pointers/pitfalls in doing it etc.

Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a start on this and have managed to get a very rough/early version at least working. It will not deal with all the in's and out's yet, but I will work on it as I go.

All I have done so far, is surround the drop down in a div that helps with additional styling. It does not cater for naming it yet, or adding html attributes etc

For anyone that is trying to do the same, I have the following so far, which you can amend to your own needs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method for displaying a custom dropdownlist
/// </summary>
public static MvcHtmlString CustomDropDownListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, IDictionary<String, Object> htmlAttributes)
{
    StringBuilder ItemsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (SelectListItem SingleListItem in selectList)
    {
            ItemsStringBuilder.AppendLine(DropDownExtensions.ListItemToOption(SingleListItem));
    }

    TagBuilder SelectTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select")
    {
        InnerHtml = ItemsStringBuilder.ToString()
    };

    TagBuilder OuterTag = new TagBuilder("div")
    {
        InnerHtml = SelectTagBuilder.ToString()
    };

    OuterTag.Attributes.Add("class", "styled-select");

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(OuterTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```